# How to change the font properties in a pie highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I'm using the [**pie Highchart.js**](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) plugin, and I'm trying to change some font properties of the labels which contains the type of the percentajes.

I tried this but does not work... **http://tinker.io/3fc64/6**

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                color: "red"
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }
        },
        credits: false,
        title: false,
        tooltip: false,
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',

            data: [
                {
                    name: 'Example1',
                    y: 40,
                    sliced: true,
                    color: "rgb(10,200,23)"
                },
                ['Example2',   12.0],
                ['Example3',       26.8],
                ['Example4',    8.5],
                ['Example5',     6.2],
                ['Example6',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

---

What I miss? Any idea or advice to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the inline style that is produced by Highschart.js, by adding a `dataLabels` block with to the `plotOptions` -> `pie` and defining some style properties:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'red',
            style: { fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif', lineHeight: '18px', fontSize: '17px' }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is your updated [tinker](http://tinker.io/3fc64/9).

If you want to control the color of the font also in the `style` block, you need to use the `fill` property.

This are the properties that get set by default (and you might want to override with the `style` settings):

```
font-family:'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:#666;
line-height:14px;
fill:#666;
```

but you can define a lot more if you need.

**Note:** You can also control the style for individual labels by passing the `dataLabels` object through the `data` block, the way you defined the style of one of your pie wedges:

```
{
name: 'Example1',
y: 40,
sliced: true,
color: 'rgb(10,200,23)',
dataLabels: { style:{ /* your style properties here */ }}
}
```

Comment: Really thanks! works perfect and you give us a good explanation!